# java.net.ConnectException: errno: 110 (Connection timed out)

Tags: java

I'm trying to connect client server, where I'm facing below mentioned error while opening connection:

```
java.net.ConnectException: errno: 110 (Connection timed out), error: 
Connection timed out (local port XXXXX to address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, remote 
port XXXX to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XX)
```

Code Snippet:

```
URL url = new URL("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/services/ServiceEngine");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write(json);
writer.close();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  jsonString.append(line);
}
br.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Seems like your server is unavailable or ```http://``` protocol is not supported

Comment: ensure that your server is running on http and on the specific port. THe server not running or incorrect ip:port in the url can also cause timeouts. From the error the IP doesnt seem to be problematic as you would have got something like no-route to host if the IP was incorrect. So double check your port.

Comment: Check telnet from client to server `telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XX   XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeouts happen when the server fails to respond in a pre-determined time period and shouldn't have much to do with the logic in your code.

You can change this time period with the HttpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout() like this:

```
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000); //Time is set in milliseconds, so 1000 is 1 second.
```

Also as another user pointed out it could be that your server isn't actually up and ready to host connections.

Comment: Setting connection time out is not what I'm expecting. what are the probable cases for this exception and resolution for that cases is I'm expecting.

Comment: Your server is either not up, not accepting http requests, or you have tried to connect to the wrong server ip/port combination.